# Canonical quantization of relativistic particle using Fourier transform

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, mathematical-physics, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation

Suppose I want to quantize the Hamiltonian of a relativistic particle on space-time $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. Setting $c=1$ for simplicity, the energy of the particle is given by $w(p) = \sqrt{|p|^{2}+m^{2}}$, $p \in \mathbb{R}^{4}$. Suppose I want to proceed as in the nonrelativistic case, where we identify:
$$x_{i} \mapsto \hat{x}_{i} \quad \mbox{and} \quad p_{i} \mapsto \hat{p}_{i} = -i\frac{\partial}{\partial_{x_{i}}}.$$
Then, formally the Hamiltonian of the system would be:
$$\hat{H} = \sqrt{-\Delta + m^{2}}.$$
I believe this can be done rigorously by using Fourier analysis. For instance, in momentum space, the operator $\sqrt{-\Delta + m^{2}}$ acts as $w(p)$. Thus, we can define $\hat{H}$ on position space $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3},dx)$ by setting:
$$ \hat{H} = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[w(p)]\mathcal{F}$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier operator, which takes Fourier transform of a function i.e. $\mathcal{F}\psi := \hat{\psi}$ and $[w(p)]$ is the operator multiplication by $w(p)$.

Regarding this construction, I have two simple questions:

- What would be an appropriate dense domain for $\hat{H}$? Should I consider:
  $$\{\psi \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3},dx): [w(p)]\mathcal{F}\psi \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3},dp)\}$$
  as a suitable dense domain for $\hat{H}$?
- Is there anything wrong with the fact that I am considering a particle on space-time $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ and getting an operator on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3},dx)$? That is, $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ becomes a theory in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: Perhaps this article can help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein–Gordon_equation

Comment: What is $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3},dx)$?

Comment: @my2cts (equivalence classes of) square integrable functions with respect to Lebesgue measure $dx$.

Comment: @my2cts The notation is quite usual in "math-community". It emphasizes the measure; for instance, in QFT the single-particle Hilbert space is often chosen to be $L^2(\mathbb R^3, \mathrm dp/2E_p)$ (or so).

Comment: @TobiasFünke I must have seen it probably 30 years ago. For accessibility it is useful to add context.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-differential_operator

Answer (score 1):

The square root of an unbounded operator like $m^2 -\Delta $ is not a local operator. Let $S$ be a set of smooth functions in the Hilbert space of consideration to provide a domain, let $S'$ the subspace with $$f\in S' : \ \int | (-\Delta f)|^2\ d^3x <\infty.$$
Then the functional approximation of the square root is for, lets say, a dense set of plane waves with a smooth cutoff at $\infty$ is
$$f_k=e^{i (\omega t - k x) - (x/s)^2}$$
with small $\omega<<m$
$$\sqrt{m^2 -\Delta} f_k = m^2\sum b_{\frac{1}{2},n} \ \left(\frac{k^2}{m^2}\right)^n $$

This means, that, by inverse Fourier transform, the action involves all derivatives up to infinity, that is the complete function.

This is seen for an approximation  of the solution by a  FEM method: $f'(x)= f(x+h)-f(x)$ = 2 point difference, $f''(x)= f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)$ =  3 point mean etc. An analytic, non polynomial function of a derivative involves a kernel of evaluation ranging over all of space in order to construct the unitary time evolution operator

$$e^{i \ t \ H} = e^{i\ t \ \sqrt{m^2-\Delta}}$$